# Create UDP listening service on Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, udp, azure-service-fabric

I have created a simple service for receiving UDP packets and am trying to deploy in Service Fabric.

When running locally, I am able to spam packets to the service (running in local SF Cluster), but when deployed to Azure the service, and even the VM, does not receive the UDP packets.

I even RDPed into the VM and installed Wireshark, my packets weren't present.
I did the same with a standard Windows DC VM, and was able to see the packets arrive.

Clearly there is an issue with the firewall which is configured upon creation of a SF cluster.

PS I have followed the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services to ensure that the LB rule is set to UDP (as is not an option upon creation).

EDIT - Note I also followed the advice on this question [Service Fabric Stateless Server Custom UDP Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902685/service-fabric-stateless-server-custom-udp-listener)

Comment: did you see this question too?  May help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792107/5946937

Comment: not that question, but was aware of the answer. Had the endpoint configured form the start. Plot twist, I got it working. It doesn't work if you modify a Load Balancer rule which was created when creating Service Fabric. But if you create a new Load Balancer rule then it seems to work fine. Potential bug with Service Fabric. Will write up an answer for my own question shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out that modifying an existing Load Balancer rule does not change the protocol on the firewall (speculation).

I created a NEW Load Balancer rule with the appropriate protocol/port and traffic was flowing.

Modifying an existing Load Balancer rule to change to an appropriate protocol does not work, and traffic ends at firewall.